# My pip is broken on Windows, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-10

Whenever I try to use pip, using any command I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qzc5n2dfsdra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qzc5n2dfsd8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\SE\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_q3.8_qzc5n2dfsd8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\SE\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qzc5n2dfsd8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\SE\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qzc5n2dfsd8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\SE\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qzc5n2dfsd8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\SE\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qzc5n2dfsd8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "C:\Users\SE\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qzc5n2dfsd8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.progress.bar import Bar, FillingCirclesBar, IncrementalBar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.progress'
PS C:\Users\SE> No module named 'pip._vendor.progress'No module named 'pip._vendor.progress'
```

I am on Windows 10, 64 bit, Python version 3.7.7.

I cannot use pip, how can I fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6261

Comment: @SwetankPoddar I did see that, but those solutions are for linux, i am on a windows os. Can you help me with the commands for the same?

Comment: @amalp12 What did you type to get the error?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: @martineau  I use this command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, but it shows  `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python\python3.7.7\lib\site-packages (20.1.1)`

Comment: @TheMaker Just about any install command  for example `pip install pytest` or `pip install pyinstaller `

Comment: @amalp12 Have you tried `python -m pip install pytest`, or `python3 -m pip install pytest`?

Comment: @TheMaker Wow, thanks `python -m pip install pytest` worked.

Comment: `pip install <modulename>` used to work just fine until yesterday I wonder what happened.

Comment: @amalp12 I Have the exact same problem: and then the code in my answer worked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) is broken after an attempted upgrade to a newer version, try the following:

1. Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and "Save As" the file using right-click.
2. Open a command prompt as an administrator
3. [`cd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cd) to the path where you saved the file, in my case
   `cd C:\Users\xyz\Downloads>` then type `python get-pip.py`. It will install all required packages, such as [`wheel`](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/) and `pip`.
4. To check if it installed correctly, type `pip --version` in the command line.

Hope my answer helps someone. Happy coding.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked.   Thanks!

Comment: @CaryH, I am glad Cary that I could help you. You are always welcome

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me as well. Here's a detailed blog step by step https://www.maheshswami.com/2021/04/how-to-fix-broken-pip-after-upgrade-or.html

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the equivalent steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6261) and [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1892) (Both are closed issues on pip's github page) on your windows machine.

On windows you can do this:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools # Sometimes setuptools might be the problem
```

This will uninstall `pip` and `setuptools`.

After which you can reinstall them using

```
python -m ensurepip
```

This will install `pip` and `setuptools`.

I have tried this on my windows 10 machine running `Python 3.7.4`!

Comment: The OP has mentioned the first link isn't relevant, and the second link doesn't mention an error.

Comment: I tried this, but still  `pip install <modulename>` still doesn't work, but using the longer version `python -m pip install <modulename>` it works fine.

Comment: @TheMaker: OP has mentioned that the first link is talking about linux and therefore OP does not know how to follow the steps mentioned over there. I found the way to uninstall pip on the second link I have mentioned.

Comment: @amalp12: That's weird, it worked fine on my machine... can you try running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` after following the steps mentioned above.

Comment: @SwetankPoddar No luck, still the same :(

Comment: @amalp12: Does it throw the same error you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: What about `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @SwetankPoddar Yes, the exact same one.

Comment: @SwetankPoddar  `pip install --upgrade pip` shows the same error too.

Comment: Okay wow. Urm, maybe it is not getting uninstalled/deleted properly. Try this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6898#issuecomment-525539142

Comment: @SwetankPoddar I did that, and installed pip all over again from  python `get-pip.py`, still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `python -m pip install pytest`. This should install it, and it will make it usable by your IDE.

Hope this helps!