# Pip 21.1 can't import InvalidSchemeCombination

Tags: python, pip

At work, we use Github actions to build and test our Pull Requests before they can be approved.
On Friday afternoon, everything was working just fine.
On Monday morning, all tests were failing pretty early, with an error showing that pip could no longer find its own exceptions. Did something change with the newest Pip?

As you can see in the errors below, our own code isn't referenced, and I'm fairly certain nothing in our flow changed between Friday and Monday (we're a small team and the approved PRs don't have anything surprising there).

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 8, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 22, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 9, in <module>
      from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 14, in <module>
      from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 29, in <module>
      from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version, site_packages, user_site
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
      from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_sysconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
      from pip._internal.exceptions import InvalidSchemeCombination, UserInstallationInvalid
  ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions' (/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py)
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/bin/pip' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074986/my-pip-is-broken-on-windows-how-can-i-fix-it/66332322#66332322

Answer (score 32):

For `macOS X`, this problem happened to me after I upgraded my homebrew,
What really worked for me is this,

```sh
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

then

```sh
python get-pip.py
```

according to the discussion in the reference, it seems only `pip version 21.1.1` fixed the problem.

Refer to the following discussion
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7217

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Thanks to your comment my pip is now running again!

Comment: When I do this from within a Conda environment, I get the following `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`. Do you know what could be the cause? In other environments this seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, but I am certain that it worked for me while my conda environment was activated. 
you can try: 
- How about running the command as a root user (sudo blah blah.) 
- Check `pip`, mine is /Users/my_name/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip similar to my python /Users/my_name/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip. using `which pip` 
- Deactivate conda environment and check your python version first, to run the commands above again. 
- How about re-install Anaconda again?  
I hope this is helpful, good luck.

Comment: I had this problem while building an image with kaniko, but it doesn't happen with `docker build`.  Reinstalling pip in my dockerfile fixed it.

Comment: One-liner: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

Answer (score 21):

> ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions'

**The reason behind this error is that the pip file is corrupted.**

**The 100% solution is as simple as follows:**

1. First execute the command: `python -m ensurepip --default-pip`
2. Download the *get-pip.py* script file from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
3. Open a terminal/command prompt (*Admin privileges*), *cd* to the folder containing the downloaded *get-pip.py* file and run: `python get-pip.py`
4. The problem has now been resolved.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! But what causes pip to get corrupted?

Comment: Worked for me too!!!

Comment: I am on Debian and had this error pop up. This reply fixed it on the first try. It reported that pip was running v20. That was updated to v23

Comment: in my case, this happened when I removed python36, installed python38. after fixing, pip was updated from v19 to v23

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there has been a [release](https://github.com/pypa/pip/releases/tag/21.1) and the last [commit](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/e7b1722efeaf4ff403142847ce1b52caedd5efcd#diff-13b930d5348c973eecd54d4bc10693f8609873818c1276a5d3ef4c4dadb5fcc4) modifying that file is from 2 days ago, however most likely it'll be something older.

Citing from the [`NEWS.rst`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/2b2a268d25963727c2a1c805de8f0246b9cd63f6) it looks like there's some migration in progress:

```
Process
-------

- Start installation scheme migration from ``distutils`` to ``sysconfig``. A
  warning is implemented to detect differences between the two implementations to
  encourage user reports, so we can avoid breakages before they happen.
```

However, it'd be for the best to [submit a bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/new?assignees=&labels=S%3A+needs+triage%2C+type%3A+bug&template=bug-report.yml) so they can release a fix if necessary.

Classic workaround, downgrade to [21.0.1](https://pypi.org/project/pip/21.0.1/) i.e. the next latest version after 21.1:

```
pip install pip==21.0.1
```

Update:

Linking the issue [#9880](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9880) submitted by OP.

Update 2:

Adjusting according to the OP's issue and another person's experience in the linked issue.

***Don't use `-I` flag*** for `pip install`, it's for installing **over** the files (hence `pip install --ignore-installed`) you have present on your system instead of the real upgrading (installing a new version, then removing the old one).

Instead, use `-U` (i.e. `pip install --upgrade`) flag which will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I've submitted a bug even though I don't have the best repro details.

Comment: That's mostly enough for the maintainers, you've provided a full traceback. Perhaps even the command you ran would be helpful to narrow down the flow e.g. perhaps it's just one specific package causing problems e.g. due to strange version/name/etc.

Comment: Thank y'all! FWIW, seems like `pip install --ignore-installed pip=={thing}` may be weird, whereas `pip install pip=={thing}` is not. Added a comment to the issue: [link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9880#issuecomment-828074854)

Comment: Update on `--ignore-installed`: should prolly avoid this: [link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9880#issuecomment-828102905)

Answer (score 9):

`pip install pip==21.0.1` did not work for my case. Running this command still raise to the same error.

You need to save [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) file in the `anaconda3\Scripts` directory or `anaconda3\envs\[env_name]\Scripts` if you are working on virtual environment. Then, you need to `cd` to this directory:

```
cd anaconda3\Scripts
```

After that run:

```
python get-pip.py pip==19.3.1
```

or

```
python get-pip.py pip==21.0.1
```

Comment: My pip was completely broken, but this worked for me. To install the 2023 version, run this line in shell:

    `python get-pip.py pip==23.0.1`

Comment: You're a savior! This doesn't require admin rights (good for work computers), is quick and solves the corrupter pip

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue on linux. Here is the solution for debian or similar versions:

First download the `get-pip.py` with:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Or go to the [url](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and copy all the contents to a new `.py` file on your system. You can name it whatever you but make sure to use same file name in the next step.

And then install a specific version of pip (execute in the same directory as the `get-pip.py` file):

```
python get-pip.py pip==21.0.1 #or any other version
```

Answer (score 2):

pip command was not working at all

For windows 10 this worked for me :-

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

after this

```
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue was encountered after updating Conda via `conda update anaconda`

Issue seems to be related to `pip v21.2.4`

As Mahmood G. B. indicated above:

1. Execute the command: `python -m ensurepip --default-pip`
2. Go to https://bootstrap.pypa.io/
3. Right click on `get-pip.py` then save file to local directory
4. Open a `terminal/command prompt (Admin privileges)`, `cd` to the folder
   containing the downloaded `get-pip.py` file and run: `python get-pip.py`
5. After installation ignore prompt to upgrade

"WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` command"

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users, this problem happened to me after I upgraded to pip v21.2.4, What really worked for me is this,

So, I deleted my older v of pip, and reinstall using CMD
Go through these steps to delete those older versions :

1. On the desktop, click or tap the File Explorer button on the taskbar.
2. Type this path in search bar `C:\Users\Win\anaconda3\Scripts`
   or old installation of python38 some way you can apply
3. Look for the file where the name is `pip3`,`pip3.8`,`pip3-script` or `pip-script` delete those files.
4. after deletion of those files reinstall pip using cmd its works fine.

Answer (score -3):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

python get-pip.py
```

Comment: This looks a lot like the top answer. Can you explain why the extra `2.7` should be used?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz If you 'll use the top answer you 'll understand why..

Comment: This isn't a question I had. The only reason I ask is that this answer came up in the Low Quality Answers review queue, likely because it was code-only with no explanation. With 9 other answers here, it would be better to explain why it's correct.