# Pip error after upgrading from python 3.7.6 to python 3.8

Tags: python, pip, anaconda3

I needed to upgrade my python to install SNScrape. After I upgrade the python, there is an error whenever I try to install packages. In the
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQZa6.png), it says ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions' (C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\exceptions.py).

I am working on Anaconda prompt, windows 10. Can somebody help me?
Should I just re-install the Anaconda? Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273590/pip-21-1-cant-import-invalidschemecombination

Comment: downgrade pip to 21.0.1

Comment: @darthbaba thanks for the suggestion, I finally solved it by removing pip manually and re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can upgrade python to 3.9

Then reinstall pip(upgrade it)

```
py -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I finally solved it by removing pip manually and re-install it.