# how to fix a broken pip install?

Tags: python, pip

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install -U --force pip
C:\Python39\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I broke my pip install trying to update it and am unsure how to fix it

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66332322/8961170

Answer (score 2):

I think you accidentally delete pip or did not install it, my suggestion is to reinstall pip by

1. Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and "Save As" the file using right-click.
2. Open a command prompt as an administrator
3. [`cd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cd) to the path where you saved the file, in my case
   python get-pip.py
   `cd C:\Users\xyz\Downloads>` then type `python get-pip.py`. It will install all required packages, such as [`wheel`](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/) and `pip`.
4. To check if it was installed correctly, type `pip --version` in the command line.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you do not have pip module in your system.

I recommend to download python again and you will have the newest possible version of pip. Or you may use "pip help" command

Comment: If the user does "*not have pip module in [their] system*", why do you continue to suggest they try to use it? Doesn't that not make sense?

Comment: yes, of course, my mistake. I will edit my suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Before downloading pip firstly check pip already installed or not. For checking open cmd type

```
pip help
```

if it responce than pip installed already.
For downloading pip then, run the following command in cmd to download the get-pip.py file:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

To install PIP run the following command in cmd :

```
 python get-pip.py
```

for confirming whether pip installed or not than again type

```
pip help
```

if it responce than pip successfully installed.

##### To check the current version of PIP,enter the following in the cmd:

```
pip --version
```

##### To upgrade PIP on Windows, enter the following in the cmd:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

###### This command uninstalls the old version of PIP and then installs the most current version of PIP.